# ada print data at address at runtime

Tags: memory, ada

Is there a way to print the data at a specific address at runtime in Ada(maybe in binary)?  I have a variable that is "corrupted" somehow, so I'm not able to do type'Image(var) to print out the data.

Comment: This is the sort of thing for which you need a debugger! You don’t say what compiler you’re using, if GNAT then the debugger is gdb. You can `watch <variable>` if needed (and you can afford the performance hit!) to get execution to stop when the variable is changed.

Comment: I wish I could use a debugger, but in the hardware where I see the error, debugger is not available.  (lynxos compiler)

Comment: Is it a shared variable ? If so it could be written with invalid data from an outside source. Perhaps try using the `'Valid` operator to diagnose when it gets corrupted ?

Comment: Have you tried using `Unchecked_Conversion` to convert the corrupted variable to some other type?  Compilers should generally implement `Unchecked_Conversion` by simply pretending the data at the variable's location has some other type; I don't think it would normally check the variable's value for validity.  If you do that, you don't need to concern yourself with the address, although there are ways to examine data at an address.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare a variable like this:

```
Debug_View : Whatever_Type_You_Want
               with Import     => True,
                    Volatile   => True,
                    Convention => Ada,
                    Address    => Some_Address;
```

you can read out/adjust the memory contents at `Some_Address`.

In earlier versions of Ada, you would write this:

```
Debug_View : Whatever_Type_You_Want;
pragma Import (Ada, Debug_View);
pragma Volatile (Debug_View);
for Debug_View'Address use Some_Address;
```

Comment: Should we give the pre-2012 version of these aspects as well?